# where can I find AdventureWorks.mdf or any other mdf file that I could attach to my database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to attach mdf file from codeplex site: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

The problem is that they have msi files, which I am clueless what they contribute, cause the database doesnt exist when I try to refer to it..

And the other file that they have Adventure2008.mdf, is higher version that my Visualstudio 2010 allows to connect to. What is the solution.. is there a simple mdf file that I can attach on my studio 2010 ultimate?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, database files can only be **attached** to a running SQL Server instance. They cannot be **attached** to Visual Studio, since Visual Studio is not SQL Server. However, Visual Studio can **connect** to a SQL Server instance and then open any database that is attached to that SQL Server instance.

The .msi files are [installers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer). If you run them, they will install code samples and the .mdf files on your computer. You may choose a location where they are installed, or accept the defaults (the default is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Samples\` according to the documentation on the [Codeplex project wiki](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Database%20Installer%20Help)).

**SQL Server**

After you have installed and located the .mdf files, you should run SQL Server Management Studio Express ([free download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593) from Microsoft), connect to your local running instance of SQL Server and attach the .mdf files.

When you have successfully attached the databases, you can connect to SQL Server from within Visual Studio using the Server Explorer.

**SQL Server Express user instance**

If you don't want to permanently attach the database to SQL Server and don't want to use SQL Server Management Studio to manage your SQL Server instance and its attached databases, you should install SQL Server **Express Edition** and work with [user instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx). This works by automatically and transparently attaching and detaching a database file to a child instance of SQL Server Express.

For this you have to copy the database file (.mdf) to the App_Data folder in your ASP.NET project. It should now show up in Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

*Note that this doesn't mean that the database is attached to Visual Studio, it just means that Visual Studio started a child instance of SQL Server Express and that child instance has attached only that particular database file. When you quit Visual Studio, the child instance will detach and quit as well.*

See: [Using SQL Server Express with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio. I havent got that... Visual Studio ultimate wont let me attach it.. why not to attach it simply, rather than being bothered connecting to my SQL server?!!?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link where you can download SQL Server Management Studio Express.

Comment: I have also added an explanation for how to user SQL Server Express. The reason you are 'bothered' connecting to SQL Server is because you chose to use SQL Server technology. I suggest you look at [SQL Server Compact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx) if this remains to much of a hassle, but I don't think the Adventure Works samples are available for SQL Server Compact.

Answer (score 0):

> And the other file that they have Adventure2008.mdf, is higher version that my Visualstudio 2010 allows to connect to.

Visual Studio 2010 should allow you to connect to any existing SQL server databases; it will certainly connect up to Server 2008 R2, which is what I use.

You haven't indicated which version(s)/edition(s) of SQL Server you have installed.

> SQL Server Management Studio. I havent got that... Visual Studio ultimate wont let me attach it.. why not to attach it simply, rather than being bothered connecting to my SQL server?!!?

Have you looked at the Server Explorer window in VS 2010 (Ctrl + Alt + S or via the View menu)? It allows you to do a lot of what Management Studio allows you to do, including creating new databases.

You said that it "won't let you attach it"... but haven't indicated how you're trying to or what errors you're getting when you do.